# Why do some questions have an amber background

Tags: support

I've looked through the help/tour.  I can't find anywhere that tells me what this colouring scheme is.  Some question summaries have a white background and some have a amber background.

This appears white but it could turn amber
[linking fortran code to library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708639/linking-fortran-code-to-library)

What does the background colour indicate?

Comment: Compare the tags on the highlighted questions to your favorite tags...

Comment: Ok got it - if it is in my favourite tags, it is amber, otherwise it is white.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean

Comment: It is the UK/US spelling - I was searching for colour.  Forgot that it is spelt as color.

Comment: Been there, done that. :)

Answer (score 14):

Question have amber background if it was tagged with tag that you have in favorite tags.